# Play services connection failed on time change

Tags: android, google-play-services

Play Services Connection failed when system time is changed to a date before 21 ,Aug 2008?
Is it the expected behaviour ?if so can anybody point me to some documentation regarding this

Comment: hello! From where do you reach to us? what is that land where the time flows slower than for us? 
More seriously, Android started around 2007, and play service is an overlay deployed during September 2012. 
Do you have a detailed crash log? Are you sure the failure is on Play Service side ?
Edit : just tested it on a phone and it's true :D

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia :

"The version history of the Android mobile operating system began with the release of the Android beta in November 2007. The first commercial version, Android 1.0, was released in September 2008."

They just don't support it before the first stable release was complete.

Edit : obligatory question, why do you need a phone set on a date prior to 21, Aug 2008?

Comment: I know it is not a valid use case :) ,however the application i am developing involves handling time change scenarios.Hence i wanted to know if there is any documentation available for the same.